# Sql Azure p4 Down for in-memory with column store index

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have the following table on azure P4 tier.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTransactions]
(
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Points] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [DeviceId] [char](36) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
   [TransactionTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
   [ActionBy] [int] NOT NULL,INDEX [idx_hash_UserTransactions_UserId] NONCLUSTERED HASH
(
   [UserId]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 524288),
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
(
   [Id] ASC
),
INDEX [UserTransactionsUIX_NonClustered] NONCLUSTERED HASH
(
   [ActionBy],
   [TransactionTypeId]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 262144)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA )
```

with high volume of inserts (around 7000 to 10000 per second). we tried to add the following
`Alter table [UserTransactions] add index UserTransactions_idx clustered columnstore`

However for some reason, when inserting into the table several transactions, the entire database goes down for around 40 seconds, then goes online back again.We tried this scenario on SQL Server 2016 On Prem, with the same result. (However we had to restart the server manually this time).We believe that adding ColumnStore index increases the performance of Selecting from the table (Along with each insert, 2x select statements happen before it, 1x select statement happens after).The behavior occurs even when manually inserting records into the table, without any select statements before or after it.

Comment: When you initiate the alter table statement to add the index it is expected that the workload will stop for some amount of time. Alter table add index statements for Hekaton are offline operations and this will block user activity while the index build is happening. Questions: 1) When you say "the entire database" - are you really saying table access? 2) Can you clarify “(Along with each insert, 2x select statements happen before it, 1x select statement happens after)”. Also feel free to email me directly at joe.sack @microsoft.com and we can check for systemic issues.

Comment: 1) No I mean literally the entire database, everything went down for 40 seconds then up for 2-3 mins then down again for 40 secs and so forth till we removed the index.
2) we are alking about stored procedure consist of four statements the third one is the insertion into "table" where two select statements happened before insertion and one select statement after.

Comment: Feel free to email me and we'll see if we can track down any issues on the back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft and they confirmed it's a bug and they will fix it in the new release